# Young Boa Imperator tries to run from my hands back into enclosure. What to do?

Tags: behavior, snakes, animal-handling

So my young Boa Imperator girl tries to run from my hands back into her enclosure. Sometimes immediately, sometimes after sitting in my hand for some time.

How should I make her more comfortable staying on me? She was calm and comfortable coming straight from the breeder but I'm new to all this. Conventional wisdom is to keep handling your snake twice a day, at least 15 minutes, but not long enough for it to become agitated and defensive. But sometimes she gets agitated and flips her tongue very slowly from the start.